# System date won't set past current date(Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, date, ubuntu, time, vmware

So I'm trying to change my system date so it is one year ahead but for some reason it won't set. So the run down:

1. I can set the date back, so anything before the current date or time works
2. I can set the HWclock with no problem.
3. I tried turning off ntpd service so it wouldn't try to auto update
4. I tried turning off network time.
5. I edited my etc/default/rcS to say UTC=no
6. I tried changing my hardware clock (which I can set ahead) and then syncing the system date to that. Nope.
7. We are using vmware/vcenter(Ubuntu 16.04.1) so I also made sure that there was no syncing going on. There wasn't.

So to recap running the date command after setting before the current date works and displays what I set. Running the date command after setting the date ahead always returns the current date. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ana, this might be a virtual machine issue. I have seen weird things happening when setting the time on a virtual machine, sometimes it won't stay at all. The virtual machine emulates a lot of things and sometimes it just doesn't cut it.

A possible workaround: try to set your host machine to the date you want, reboot, and then try again to change the time on the virtual machine.